# Можно ли сделать JOIN через Spring Query Methods

Tags: spring, spring-data

Например

```
Page<Book> findBookByTitleContainingIgnoreCase(String title, Pageable pageable);
Page<Book> findBookByYearEquals(Integer year, Pageable pageable);
Page<Book> findBookByTitleContainingIgnoreCaseAndYearEquals(String title, Integer year, Pageable pageable);
```

Как написать JOIN в такой конструкции, например найти книги по имени автора (предполагается наличие отношения one-to-many (одна книга несколько авторов))

```
введите сюда код
```

Answer (score 2):

А в вашей объектной модели должна быть связь между нужными сущностями. ( @oneToMany или @manyToOne и тд.)
Тогда в репозитории сможете искать по полю с чайлдом.